# Scrolling Unavailable When Window is Shrunk for HTML/CSS Page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a registration page using HTML and CSS, however, I cannot get the page to scroll up and down when I shrink the window small enough to the point the form is no longer fully visible. I have tried to add the 'overflow-x: scroll;', but I haven't successfully gotten it to work. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="registerStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <label class="logo">Homemade</label>
    <div class="registrationContainer">
        <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
            

            <h1>Create Account</h1>
    
            <div class="inputOption">
                <label class="inputOptionLabel">Your Name</label>
                <input type="name" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="inputOption">
                <label class="inputOptionLabel" for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="inputOption">
                <label class="inputOptionLabel" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="inputOption">
                <label class="inputOptionLabel" for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
            </div>
    
            <button type="submit">Register</button>

            <label>Already have an account?</label>
            <a href="#">Sign In</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* Resets some defualt set styles */
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Container holding registration form */
.registrationContainer{
    /* Center the form in middle of the page */
    position: fixed;
    top: 370px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Style within form */
    padding: 25px 20px;

    /* Style of form */
    width: 350px;
    height: 396px;

    /* Border around the form */
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(201, 201, 201);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 2%;
}

/* Positioning/style of logo within registration form */
.logo{
    /* Positioning of logo */
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* Logo style */
    color: rgb(248, 166, 89);
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Positioning/style of heading within registration form */
h1{
    /* Positioning of heading */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

    /* Heading style */
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.inputOptionLabel{
    /* Positioning of labels */
    display: block;


    /* Label styles */
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

input{
    /* Positioning of labels */
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    /* Label text styles */
    font-size: 16px;

    /* Label Style */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(201, 201, 201);
}

button{
    /* Positioning of labels */
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;

    /* Label text styles */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;

    /* Label Style */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    background: rgb(248, 166, 89);
    outline: none;
    border: 1px rgb(255, 160, 71) solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgb(250, 183, 120);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.registrationContainer` and `position: absolute` to `.logo`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Container holding registration form */

.registrationContainer {
  /* Center the form in middle of the page */
  position: relative;
  top: 370px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Style within form */
  padding: 25px 20px;
  /* Style of form */
  width: 350px;
  height: 396px;
  /* Border around the form */
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(201, 201, 201);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2%;
}


/* Positioning/style of logo within registration form */

.logo {
  /* Positioning of logo */
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Logo style */
  color: rgb(248, 166, 89);
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Positioning/style of heading within registration form */

h1 {
  /* Positioning of heading */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* Heading style */
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.inputOptionLabel {
  /* Positioning of labels */
  display: block;
  /* Label styles */
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

input {
  /* Positioning of labels */
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* Label text styles */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Label Style */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(201, 201, 201);
}

button {
  /* Positioning of labels */
  display: block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  /* Label text styles */
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Label Style */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: rgb(248, 166, 89);
  outline: none;
  border: 1px rgb(255, 160, 71) solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgb(250, 183, 120);
}
```

```html
<label class="logo">Homemade</label>
<div class="registrationContainer">
  <form action="/users/register" method="POST">


    <h1>Create Account</h1>

    <div class="inputOption">
      <label class="inputOptionLabel">Your Name</label>
      <input type="name" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="inputOption">
      <label class="inputOptionLabel" for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="inputOption">
      <label class="inputOptionLabel" for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="inputOption">
      <label class="inputOptionLabel" for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Register</button>

    <label>Already have an account?</label>
    <a href="#">Sign In</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Setting them to `position: fixed` prevents them from being scrollable elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Add this as your .registrationContainer centering code. The mix of fixed position with the transforms is causing the issue with your scroll being locked and unavailable at smaller screen sizes.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Also, add this to your centering for your .logo label element. This will stick it above your page login form.

All elements are responsive as well.